# Subtract values associated with repeating variables in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 'Yellow'], [2100, 'Blue'], [3400, 'Purple'], [3416,'Grey'], [3420,'Purple'], [1100,'Yellow']], columns=['Time', 'Marker'])
df

    Time    Marker
0   1000    Yellow
1   2100    Blue
2   3400    Purple
3   3416    Grey
4   3420    Purple
5   1100    Yellow
```

Goal: 1. Iterate through column 'Marker'. 2. For every cell with a consecutively repeating value (but not necessarily adjacent; for example, 'purple' repeats but is not right after the first occurrence), test whether they are less than 1,000 ms apart (by subtracting the value of the 'time' column for the two instances). If the difference is less than 1,000 - delete the row of the second occurrence.

I started with this, but am stuck on how to proceed:

```
for val in df['Marker']:
     df[~((df['Marker']==df['Marker'].shift())&(df['Marker'].isin(['180','181'])))]
```

In this example, we would end up with only the first stance of 'purple' because the second instance occurs too soon:

```
    Time    Marker
0   1000    Yellow
1   2100    Blue
2   3400    Purple
3   3416    Grey
```

I would love to hear suggestions.

Comment: Why is 1100 Yellow still there? The difference to the previous Yellow is 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to drop differences strictly superior to 100, use `groupby` on Marker and compute the `diff`. If lower than (`lt`) 100, keep the row:

```
df[~df.groupby('Marker')['Time'].diff().lt(100)]
```

output:

```
   Time  Marker
0  1000  Yellow
1  2100    Blue
2  3400  Purple
3  3416    Grey
5  1100  Yellow
```

Comment: OP said less than 1000 though... maybe a typo

Comment: @timgeb I just see it now, I guess my brain autocorrected to 100 ^^ we'll see if this was correct

Comment: I'd use `.ge(100)` btw to save the negation operation.

Comment: @timgeb no because this would drop the NaN that result from the diff ;) the negation is actually a trick to keep them

Comment: @timgeb thank you, this is short and elegant and works. I did mean 1,000- but that's inconsequential. Still wonder if there is a way to apply this only to certain 'Markers' (ie Yellow and Purple, but not others).

Comment: @arkadiy sure, basic combination of boolean masks. This is getting into spoonfeeding territory so maybe you should try it yourself first. ;)

Comment: an OR mask on the non target values should do ;)